# Is there a 3rd party tool to create a heat map of all activities in a specific area?

Tags: gps, maps, strava

I'm familiar with Jonathan O'Keeffe's Strava Multiple Ride Mapper (tied to the Strava API) but I'm interested in mapping all activities in a certain geopgraphy, not just those I've done.

My goal is to find new trails that I haven't explored so I'm interested in seeing all activities in a region from all users.

(Bonus points if it can then remove the roads/trails that I've logged activities on.)

ref: http://www.jonathanokeeffe.com/strava/map.php

Comment: See http://labs.strava.com/heatmap/

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me

Comment: Thanks @PeteH. Seems difficult to have a topic of cycling without including some product or service recommendations.

Comment: I forgot about Labs though, as @Kibbee suggested. I just wish they could remove the areas I've already done.  Thank you though!

Comment: @PeteH It seems to be pretty clearly a request for a product recommendation to me. But feel free to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @mattsolar The Stack Exchange Q&A format [doesn't work well with product recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). The Bicycles SE community in particular [toyed with the idea of keeping them open](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping), but [ultimately decided](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/828/adding-shopping-recommendations-to-the-vote-to-close-page) that they weren't a good fit. You are always welcome to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome).

Comment: @jimirings I interpreted the question as "does something exist", not "can you recommend one". Mattsolar, you could try rephrasing the question so it is more clearly worded along these lines, though I suspect the die has already been cast

Comment: @PeteH I don't see a functional difference. The answers would still end up being a string of equally valid recommendations. But whether or not it makes a difference would be a good topic for Meta. And again, you have enough rep to cast a reopen vote. If you cast one and the community decided to reopen it, I wouldn't squash that decision.

Comment: I asked a question about Strava on the WebApps stack a while ago. Tumbleweed. This feels like the best place for this question, since it's specific to a system already chosen. Asking for advice on Strava vs MapMyRide vs Endomondo vs ... would definitely be #productrec though.

Comment: @jimirings thanks for the comments & help. I'll put more time into Meta. 